# How can I disable the touch features from Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

When I hooked up my touchscreen monitor to my Win7 machine, the touchscreen basically worked like a mouse. I had no multi-touch features, tap was a click, that was it. After rebooting the machine, Windows activated all the touch features (blue circle when tapping, multitouch, ...) and I don't know how to disable them again.

All I want is the touchscreen to work exactly like a mouse, but I can only find the options to disable multi-touch and the touchscreen all together.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [How to completely disable Touch Screen on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/670502/)