# How to Disable Your Computer’s Touch Screen in Windows server 2016?

Tags: windows-installer, windows-server-2016, touchscreen

I want disable touch screen in my msi all in one.
My OS is windows server 2016.
I can disable touch screen from device manager but after restart pc touch screen enable automatically.

How to fix this?

Comment: Sorry. I edit title

Comment: In Windows Services, disable *Tablet PC Input Service*. https://superuser.com/questions/670502/how-to-completely-disable-touch-screen-on-windows-7

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Windows server 2016 have not 'Tablet PC Input Service'